# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using .prepend()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an empty div (`<div class="myclass"></div>`) into another div container using jQuery `.prepend()` but i keep running into an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Below is what i have so far. Please any suggestions on what might be wrong? Thanks

Error Message I am getting

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$$('#global_content').prepend($('<p>Test</p>'))')
```

HTML Code & JavaScript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$$('#global_content').prepend($('<p>Test</p>'));
});
</script>


<div id="global_content">
I want to add a div here above all other divs in this container using jQuery
  <div class="myclass1"></div>
   <div class="myclass2"></div>
   <div class="myclass3"></div>
  <div class="myclass4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have an extra `$` in front of `$('#global_content')`

Comment: Why two `$$` in front of the call?

Comment: That's Prototype. jQuery only uses a single `$`. Be careful when mixing the two libraries.

Comment: `.prepend()` could also receive normal string instead of jQuery' object - `$('#global_content').prepend('<p>Test</p>');`

Comment: Thanks for the response guys i noticed that myself and i removed it but then i get this error message now `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('#global_content').prepend')`

Answer (score 1):

here is mistake:

```
$$
```

before the selector which is causing the error.

Instead of :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$$('#global_content').prepend($('<p>Test</p>'));
});
</script>
```

do :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('#global_content').prepend($('<p>Test</p>'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks I did remove like you suggested but then i get this new error message now `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('#global_content').prepend')`

Comment: give a try to this it appends or not:$('#global_content').prepend('<p>Test</p>');

Answer (score 0):

After several tries i finally figured it out. Thanks to Ehsan Sajjad, and the rest of you. Here was what i did to get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery('#global_content').prepend('<mainbg></mainbg>');
</script>
```